# Unable to transition to VisualState - "No applicable name scope"

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, porting

I've ported a silverlight TemplatedControl to WPF, and while it behaves mostly the same, the animations no longer work.

When I call `VisualStateManager.GoToState()` it returns false. In an attempt to force this manually, I followed someone elses recommendation and looked up the the visual state group by name, and force the storyboard to run:

```
        foreach (VisualStateGroup vsg in VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(part_LayoutRoot))
        {
            VisualState vs = vsg.States.Cast<VisualState>().FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == visualState);

            if (vs == null)
                throw new ApplicationException("No visual state found with name: " + visualState);

            vs.Storyboard.Begin();
            break;
        }
```

However this throws the exception`No applicable name scope exists to resolve the name 'PART_MyPart'`
 when I call `Storyboard.Begin()`.

Upon further investigation, the VisualStateManager, visual states and storyboards all return null when `NameScope.GetNameScope()` is called on them, so I attempted to set them manually in code as well:

```
        var nameScope = NameScope.GetNameScope(vs.Storyboard);
        if (nameScope == null)
        {
            nameScope = NameScope.GetNameScope(part_LayoutRoot);
            NameScope.SetNameScope(vsg, nameScope);
            NameScope.SetNameScope(vs, nameScope);
            NameScope.SetNameScope(vs.Storyboard, nameScope);
        }
```

However, the exception continues to get raised, and I can't for the life of me think why. This works exactly as expected in silverlight.

Can anyone shed any light on why there would be different behavior between silverlight and WPF with regards to NameScope?

Thanks

Comment: Can we see the XAML of the template? You shouldn't have to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve a named element within your control template and call `storyboard.Begin(_retrievedElement)` instead of just `storyboard.Begin()` to solve the "No applicable name scope" problem. The name scope of the passed framework element will be applied to the storyboard in that case. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.begin.aspx for further information on the different overloads of this method.

Unfortunately, I cannot reconstruct why the Visual States Manager does not work for your control.

**Update**: I might have figured out why your control templates work in Silverlight, but not in WPF. Details in the next answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also might have a clue why your ported control template does not work: in WPF, it is not possible to use bindings in storyboards within visual states. Consider the following template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="5" Background="White" BorderBrush="#FFB0B0B0">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.3"/>
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                            To="{Binding (Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color), ElementName=ButtonBorder}"
                            Duration="0"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#00000000"/>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

</ControlTemplate>
```

The important part is the Visual State "MouseOver" where an element binding is used: this code will execute in Silverlight perfectly well while in WPF the data binding engine will tell you that it cannot find the element with the name "ButtonBorder" (look at the Output window to trace data binding errors). This has to do with the namespace problem I mentioned in my earlier answer.
A workaround for this problem would be like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="5" Background="White" BorderBrush="#FFB0B0B0">
            <Border.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOverStoryboard">
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                            To="{Binding (Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color), ElementName=ButtonBorder}"
                            Duration="0"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </Border.Resources>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.3"/>
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOverStoryboard}">

                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#00000000"/>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

</ControlTemplate>
```

Now, the storyboard is added to the Resource property of the root template element and thus the name scope seems to fit. In the visual state, just use the Static Resource Markup Extension to reference the storyboard. Note that this XAML will not run in Silverlight, so you cannot share the file in both projects. Also, Blend is not able to process this markup so this would have to be written by hand.

Hope this helps.